# Session management by storing recently fetched data at server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, database, session, server

We have a scenario where the server and db are far away. So the connection between them is slow.

Hence we are planning a strategy to maintain user sessions at the server memory itself. This means all the user fetched data, from db will reside at server and further changes to this data is kept at the server for a time interval (say 3 hours). The data is then saved to the database after every 3 hours.

Also, when another user requests the same data, it has to be fetched from the server memory if found.

Any ideas/ existing frameworks/ ORM to implement such a design?

Comment: Hi Srimol, could you clarify what's your question?

Comment: So when the server, or server process, is restarted all changed to the data from (at most) the last 3 hours is gone? Sounds like you should look into database replication.

Comment: @robertklep good suggestion. I was unaware of db replication. But have you heard of any frameworks or ORMs that handle this concern including the one problem which you mentioned? Like the server can be safely restarted by saving all the data.

Comment: Database replication is something that's typically built into databases. MongoDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. It _would_ mean running a replica of the database on two locations.